# Get text from StatusBar in Windows by WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi

I am writing an automation for a program. I can get the `HWND` of its `StatusBar` by `FindWindowExA()`, and it has child `TextControl`s that contain text which I want to get. How to get the text from those child controls?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

char buf[1024];
char buf2[1024];
char buf3[1024];
char buf4[1024];

__stdcall BOOL EnumPropsCAllBack(HWND p1, LPCSTR p2, HANDLE p3)
{
    char *p = (char *)p3;
    HANDLE h1 = GetPropA(p1, p2);
    std::cout << "EnumProps " << p1 << " " << /*p2 << */" " << p3 << " " << h1 << std::endl;//reading p2 fails?
    return 1;
}

__stdcall BOOL EnumChildWindowsCAllBack(HWND wnd, LPARAM p)
{
    //
    GetClassNameA(wnd, buf3, 1024);
    GetWindowTextA(wnd, buf, 1024);
    std::cout << "EnumChildWindows " << wnd << " " << buf << " " << buf3 << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

void doHwndRecursive(HWND wnd, int gl, int fl)
{
    HWND wnd1 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < gl; i++)
        buf2[i] = ' ';
    buf2[gl] = 0;
    GetWindowTextA(wnd, buf, 1024);
    GetClassNameA(wnd, buf3, 1024);
    std::cout << buf2 << " " << wnd << " " << buf << " " << buf3 << std::endl;
    if(!strcmp(buf3, "msctls_statusbar32") || fl)
    {
        LRESULT len = SendMessageA(wnd, WM_GETTEXT, 255, LPARAM(buf3));
        std::cout << "Found StatusBar! " << len << " " << buf3 << std::endl;
        EnumPropsA(wnd, EnumPropsCAllBack);
        EnumChildWindows(wnd, EnumChildWindowsCAllBack, 0);
        fl = 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        wnd1 = FindWindowExA(wnd, wnd1, 0, 0);
        if(wnd1 == 0)
            break;
        else
            doHwndRecursive(wnd1, gl + 1, fl);
    }
}

int main()
{
    HWND wnd1 = 0;
    HWND wnd = 0;
    wnd = FindWindowExA(0, 0, 0, 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) // for not infinite loop
    {
        wnd = FindWindowExA(0, wnd, 0, 0);
        buf[1023] = 0;
        GetWindowTextA(wnd, buf, 1024);
        if(!strcmp(buf, "src.txt – notepad"))
        {
            wnd1 = 0;
            doHwndRecursive(wnd, 0, 0);
        }
        if(wnd == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "end " << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << wnd1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
 0x5d088a src.txt - notepad Notepad
  0x2a0136  Edit
  0x80b72  msctls_statusbar32
Found StatusBar! 0
EnumProps 0x80b72  0x10005 0x10005
EnumProps 0x80b72  0x29a0000 0x29a0000
end
0
```

For example, Notepad has the `TextControl`s in its `StatusBar`, which is seen in Inspect Object from WinSDK.

In 7zFileManager, the `StatusBar` contains `TextControl`s. This method can get text from the first control. How to enumerate those controls by simple WinAPI and get their texts?

Comment: To automate UI on Windows, you should use UI Automation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statusbar does not have child windows, the statusbar itself draws the panel sections (known as "parts").

It supports the `SB_GETTEXTLENGTH` and [`SB_GETTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/sb-gettext) messages but your memory buffer needs to be in the same process (`VirtualAllocEx`).

The correct solution is to use MSAA/[UI automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) where possible.